# (Keras) Apply pad_sequences for deeper levels // Variable label length

Tags: python, keras

I got a label data shaped `(2000,2,x)` where x is between 100 and 250 for each of the 2000 sets with 2 being the x and y coordinates. To my understanding, fitting my model like in the code below would only match the length of the coordinates.

```
model.fit(
    x=train_data, 
    y=keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_labels, maxlen=250),
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

So how can I bring all of these labels to the same length since that seems necessary in order to use them to train the model?

Comment: depends on your model; which we  dont see here. See my answer for how you could pad the last dimension which this isn't doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `np.pad` works here (while `np.moveaxis + sequence.padding` didn't). So I'm iterating over my input twice; once to get the maximum length and a second time to apply `np.pad` to a new array that got the shape `(training_samples, coordinates, maximum_sequence_length)`.

While I don't know whether padding distorts the output of the CNN-LSTM, I'm glad that the above error doesn't arise any longer.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine labels are going to be a somewhat sparse matrix with shape `( 2000, 2, 250)`  if you account for padding right? And you're attempting predicting  for each example a 2D matrix with (2, 250)?

Anyways, the padding you currently have will only affect the coordinate's dimension.

A hack to get padding on the last dimension would be to permute the axis of the data and add padding then permute back to original shape:

```
perm_y = np.moveaxis(y, 1, 2)
padded_perm_y = sequence.padding(y, max_len=250, padding='post',
                truncating='post')
padded_y = np.moveaxis(padded_perm_y, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Yeah, you got that right. I want the net to learn a sequence with which the input image is generated.
And I'm really sorry to not mention this earlier: Since the sequences are of different length, my `y` has to be a list with arrays of shape `(2,178)` (for example).  But that just got me the idea that I could just iterate over all the array and append zeroes until the got the right shape.

Edit: As for the model, it consists of 2x (Conv2D + MaxPooling), a LSTM and a dense layer, but it's not final yet.

Answer (score 0):

For padding sequences with deeper levels (list of lists of lists,..) you can use ragged tensors and convert to tensors/arrays. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
padded_y = tf.ragged.constant(train_labels).to_tensor(0.)
```

This pads with 0.